# (Learning Bash) How to run multiple postgresql command from bash file

Tags: bash, postgresql, ubuntu

This is what I am doing manually.

```
user@host: sudo -u postgres psql
postgres=# create database myproj;
postgres=# create user myuser with password 'mypass';
postgres=# alter role myuser set client_encoding to 'utf8';
postgres=# alter role myuser set default_transaction_isolation to 'read committed';
postgres=# alter role myuser set timezone to 'UTC';
postgres=# grant all privileges on database myproj to myuser;
postgres=# \q
```

The question is if I want to save it to .sh file and run, what should be the content. something like this?

```
sudo -u postgres psql -c "create database myproj;"
sudo -u postgres psql -c "create user myuser with password 'mypass';"
sudo -u postgres psql -c "alter role myuser set client_encoding to 'utf8';"
sudo -u postgres psql -c "alter role myuser set default_transaction_isolation to 'read committed';"
sudo -u postgres psql -c "alter role myuser set timezone to 'UTC';"
sudo -u postgres psql -c "grant all privileges on database myproj to myuser;"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a *Here document*

```
$cat yourscript.sh
sudo -u postgres psql <<'INP'
create database myproj;
create user myuser with password 'mypass';
..
..
INP
```

If you wish to isolate the SQL commands from shell, put it in a separate .sql file and call using `-f` option or psql `\i` option.

```
$cat dbscript.sql
     create database myproj;
     create user myuser with password 'mypass';
..
```

Run it as

```
sudo -u postgres psql -U <yourusername> -d <yourdbname> -f dbscript.sql
```

Or

```
sudo -u postgres psql <<INP
\i /path/dbscript.sql
```

Comment: I can not save sql file so I am trying first approach. I have prepared the .sh file at pastebin. If possible can you please check if I understood your answer correctly?

Comment: The first and last cd commands are just to understand that this is part of large .sh file. Is this ok?

Comment: @Rahul : The `cd` command's not needed. Rest seems Ok. Please verify it in your test environment before running.

Comment: `cd` commands are there to confirm that this is part of larger .sh file and can work that way.